# Spring Authorization server schema related questions

Tags: spring-authorization-server

Kindly provide assistance with the following:

1. Schema for Spring Authorization Server version 1.1.1
2. Can the table name and column names be changed in the same?
3. What is the difference between oauth_client_details and oauth2_registered_client?

Is this schema correct? https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-oauth/blob/main/spring-security-oauth/src/test/resources/schema.sql

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Spring Security OAuth is no longer supported and has reached [end-of-life](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/07/end-of-life-for-spring-security-oauth). The schema you linked is not correct for Spring Authorization Server because SAS is a separate (new) project and is not backwards compatible with the deprecated project.

Second, the schemas used for the JDBC implementations of [core services](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html) are:

- [oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql)
- [oauth2-authorization-schema.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql)
- [oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql)

[This implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/e5fcbe422be1a73240ac7d8b40f165651fb01ab8/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/JdbcRegisteredClientRepositoryTests.java#L285-L419) and [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/e5fcbe422be1a73240ac7d8b40f165651fb01ab8/oauth2-authorization-server/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/JdbcRegisteredClientRepositoryTests.java#L261-L272) provide an example of customizing the schema and column names. You may also be interested in the examples from [How-to: Implement core services with JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-jpa.html) which would give you full flexibility to customize the schema however you want.